# I want to align grid in center

Tags: css

As you see my code grid_2 has float left.  so i added center class to fix it in center but div block is floating left. I want to place this grid_2 div in center. Can any one help me to fix this?

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="center"><div class="grid_2">Content goes here  </div> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid_0 {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
}

.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_3c, .grid_4, .grid_4c {
    margin-left : 1.00%;
    margin-right : 1.00%;
    margin-bottom : 15px;
    float : left;
    display : block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

.center{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.grid_1 { width: 98%; }

.grid_2 { width: 48%; }
```

Please find the link below http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/AQbS6/5/

Comment: try this margin:0 auto

Comment: could you please post some more of your html code? Makes it easier to understand what you really want :) but normally you use margin:auto when centering stuff.

Comment: I tried that already in .center. i want this float : left  to remain same for .grid_2 as i have requirements in other pages

Comment: Got solution and here is the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/AQbS6/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Here problem lies in width of grid_2.

As width of grid_2 = 48% of entire page, it will always be on lefter side of page.

Just remove width of grid and you will get Your answer

If you are using same class on other pages too then add update your class with following properties :

```
.grid_2 { width: 48%;float:none;margin: auto !important; }
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/2DxsA/3/

Comment: But i'm using the same class in other pages too. so i cant change the width.

Comment: I have updated my answer to support same width of 48%

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin to = auto on grid 2, overide the float and it will be centered. I've added coloured borders so that you can see the positions of the divs

[JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/gegugumo/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
.center{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.grid_1 { width: 98%; }

.grid_2 { width: 48%; float:none; border: 1px solid green;margin: 0 auto !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.grid_0 {
 width: 100%;
}

.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_3c, .grid_4, .grid_4c {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.grid_1 { width: 98%; }

.grid_2 { width: 48%; }

p{
 clear:both;
 display:block;
}

label{
 float:left;
}
```

simplified version of your css with the result you like.